# not receiving data from android in symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony project and now I am trying to receive the data from android device and access that data via json encoding but the data is not actually received. Instead a layout.html.twig is sent back as the response to android app.

I am using the following code to receive the data in my controller...

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $response = new Response(json_encode(array('name' => $email)));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    echo $response;
```

But the browser says Undefined index: email in /home/external/public_html/src/Apostle/ApiBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Where am I going wrong?????

Answer (score 1):

First, about the email error, the request sent to the controller doesn't have the 'email' post parameter.

Then you have to return the response in the symfony controller, not just echo it.

**UPDATE:**

I think you shouldn't use the $_POST directly in symfony, please use the $this->getRequest()->get() method, or $this->getRequest->request->get() method for specific POST parameters.

Comment: the post parameter sent to controller is 'email' and i have tried return instead echo but still i did not receive the value from android

Comment: $this->getRequest->request->get('email') returns the same error ?

Comment: Please try this in your controller var_dump($this->getRequest()->request->all())

Comment: yes, this will dump all the post parameters the symfony controller has access to

Comment: this also did not serve my purpose..the value is null..it seems my controller does not have access to the data..Can you help for that?

Comment: Then I can say that your android request does not provide symfony with the post parameter

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code.

- You should **not** be reading the `$_POST` variable. Always use `$this->getRequest()->get('email')` instead of `$_POST['email']`.
- It is generally considered better to instantiate a `JsonResponse` then to instantiate a `Response` and set its `Content-type` to `application/json`.
- The reason you are getting the notice with `$_POST` and a null pointer with `$this->getRequest()->get()` is because your client (your android device) did not send the email parameter.
- You should not `echo` the `Response`, you should return it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: but the client(the android device) do send the 'email' parameter as the request printed there displays it well.

Comment: could you elaborate on how the device sends that parameter? Maybe it sends it serialized on a json string. Please, edit your question to add the contents of `print_r($this->getRequest());`